# 'class QFile' has no member named 'setName'

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Здравствуйте. Не нашёл ответ в гугле, решил здесь задать. Подскажите где закралась ошибка.

```
QFile file;
QString f = "/mnt/tmpfs/"; f += n; f += ".txt";
// проверяем наличие файла на месте
if (QFile::exists(f) == false)   // проверка на существование
{
    file.setName(f); // создали файл
    if (QFile::exists(f) == false) qDebug () << error(3);
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку.

```
error: 'class QFile' has no member named 'setName'
         file.setName(f); // создали файл
              ^
```

Comment: Зачем гуглить, когда есть официальная документация?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для создания файла надо последовательно вызвать функции:

```
void QFile::setFileName ( const QString & name )
bool QFile::open(OpenMode mode)
```

Получается следующий код

```
QFile file;
QString f = "/mnt/tmpfs/"; f += n; f += ".txt";
// проверяем наличие файла на месте
if (QFile::exists(f) == false)   // проверка на существование
{
    //имя файла
    file.setFileName (f); 
    // создаем файл
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) 
    {
         qDebug () << error(3);//ошибка создания
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Брал инфу из http://qt-doc.ru/rabota-s-fajlami-klass-qfile.html как оказалось нужно было писать setFileName в место setName

Comment: @shaman888 прошло всего 5 лет...

Comment: @Владимир-Мартьянов я не понял вас.

Comment: @shaman888 Что непонятного-то? Читать надо актуальные мануалы. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html

Comment: @shaman888 статья, по которой вы что-то делали 5-летней давности.